# 2 colors on line chart WinForms

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, charts

I download some data from a SQL database and display the data in `dataGriView1` and `dataGriView2`. Then, I create a column chart.

I have a problem adding two different colors to the chart so that the data from `dataGriView1` has a different color than `dataGriView2`. How can I achieve the desired result?

```cs
chart1.Series["Wydajnosc"].Points.Clear();
 
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
    this.chart1.Series["Wydajnosc"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["WYDAJNOSC"].Value.ToString()));
    this.chart1.Series["Srednia"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text.ToString()));             
}

for (int j = 0; j < dataGridView2.Rows.Count - 1; j++)
{
    this.chart1.Series["Wydajnosc"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells["WYDAJNOSCII"].Value.ToString()));
    this.chart1.Series["Srednia"].Points.AddXY(dataGridView2.Rows[j].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), Convert.ToDouble(textBox6.Text.ToString()));
}
```

[image]

Comment: Your tags are wrong, you are either using winforms or wpf. Your question should be more clear.

Comment: You should not add both source to the same chart series. Create individual series for each dataGridView and define individual colors for them.